# Do number of trees affect efficiency of hunting?

Tags: banished

Will a hunting cabin in the middle of a dense forest produce more food and leather than one in an open plain?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is currently unknown, but they *seem* to work best in forested areas. Personally I plop down a hunter's hut next to my forester/gatherer/herbalist outpost to provide some food variety and early game leather. It is not an efficient pure food source.

[Source](http://banished-wiki.com/wiki/Tutorials/Tips)